# Java rejects certificate following IP address change

Tags: java, ssl

Following an enforced IP address change from our host suppliers, it appears our Java application no longer accepts the certificate (which hasn't changed).

We are getting a

```
    ValidatorException:PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target
```

exception when calling the site.

Nothing else has changed except the IP address the app is definitely resolving the hostname to the new IP, and the certificate is accepted by all browsers.

Does anyone know of any reason this might happen, or anyway of debugging the exact issue.

In summary, Java webstart application can't reconnect to the server it was launched from following IP address change.

Comment: Unless you have set the IPs as CN in the cert: Something else must have changed. Certificates don't care about IPs. "unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target" means something is wrong with the certificate sent by the server, e.g. it's not trusted because there is no matching root certificate in the local trust store. WRT debugging: what is the `caused by` error? (Also :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html )

Comment: @zapl thats whats got us confused, nothing else has changed and everything worked fine on Friday. The exception is raised by a call using apache's HTTPClient 3.x.

Comment: Amongst the things that could have changed: is the root & all intermediate certificates you have in truststore & server side still valid?

Comment: @zapl it seems the java application is getting the default plesk panel certificate instead of the site one, so this is now the wrong site I guess. Thanks for the help. Good point about the validity of the certificates as they could have gone out over the weekend,